# How do I use the Supply monad to create a function that generates globally unique names?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, unique, monads, state-monad

### Background:

I'm doing a code translation project that requires me to generate variable names. None of the names I generate should be duplicates of each other.

I'm really frustrated since this would be stupidly simple and elegant with a Python generator function.

### What I've tried:

The way I was doing it before was to pass a counter variable down through recursive calls to my translate code, and pass the (possibly incremented) counter back up in the return value of basically every function.

This was really messy: it added an extra parameter to keep track of to each of these functions; and worse still it forced me to work with messy tuple return values where I would otherwise have a simple unary return value.

I've never really gotten proficient with monads in my short time with Haskell, but I had an inkling that I could use a wrapper on the `State` monad to simulate a global counter variable. After 3 days of messing around trying to grok monads and make one of my own, then trying to alter someone else's monads to generate the values I needed, I've finally resigned myself to straight-up using someone else's high-level monad (perhaps with a few alterations.)

### My problem now:

I've identified the [MonadSupply](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/New_monads/MonadSupply) and [MonadUnique](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/New_monads/MonadUnique) modules as a couple which likely provide the simple kind of interface I need. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to use them.

In particular the `MonadSupply` module documentation provides this nice example use case:

```
runSupplyVars x = runSupply x vars
    where vars = [replicate k ['a'..'z'] | k <- [1..]] >>= sequence
```

Looks like what I want! Once I got the module to compile I checked the type of this function in the interpreter:

```
> :t runSupplyVars
runSupplyVars :: Supply [Char] a -> Identity (a, [[Char]])
```

I've tried passing lots (hours worth) of different things to this function, with no success. I also tried passing the function to some various other functions to see if they would provide the parameters I needed implicitly. No luck so far.

### The Questions:

Could someone please provide an example use case of this `runSupplyVars` function?

Would it be possible to do what I'm thinking with it? I want to have a function I can call from anywhere in the program, which will provide me with a different variable name or integer on each call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To actually use the `Supply` monad you should structure your code with [`do` notation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation) and call the `supply` function when you actually need a name.

For example, this will produce a new variable name prefixed with `var_`, just to show how you might get something from the supply and use it:

```
newVar :: Supply [Char] [Char]
newVar = do
    name <- supply
    return ("var"_++name)
```

You'll need to structure your whole program around the `Supply` monad and then only call `runSupplyVars` once at the top-level, otherwise different parts of the program will have independent supplies and so might reuse the same variable name.

Finally, you'll need [`runIdentity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Identity.html) from `Control.Monad.Identity` to unpack the result of `runSupplyVars` into the underlying tuple of type `(a, [[Char]])`, and then throw away the second value which is just the (infinite) list of unused names. You might be better off redefining `runSupplyVars` to do this for you:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity

[...]

runSupplyVars :: Supply [Char] a -> a
runSupplyVars x = fst (runIdentity (runSupply x vars))
    where vars = [replicate k ['a'..'z'] | k <- [1..]] >>= sequence
```

Here's a more complete example putting it all together. Note the different monads with which `do` notation is used - `IO` for the `main` function, and `Supply [Char]` for `realProgram` and probably most of the rest of the code in a bigger version:

```
import MonadSupply
import Control.Monad.Identity

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let result = runSupplyVars realProgram
    print result

realProgram :: Supply [Char] Int
realProgram = do
    x <- newVar
    return 0

newVar :: Supply [Char] [Char]
newVar = do
    name <- supply
    return ("var_"++name)

runSupplyVars :: Supply [Char] a -> a
runSupplyVars x = fst (runIdentity (runSupply x vars))
    where vars = [replicate k ['a'..'z'] | k <- [1..]] >>= sequence
```

Comment: I guess my biggest problem is with the `do` notation then. If I call `runSupplyVars` from the first line of my `do` block, like `p <- runSupplyVars`, then it seems like every other line in the block eneds to be of type `Supply [Char] t0 -> b0` (according to my compilation error messages). I assume that means that whatever top-level function I use to kick off my translation (say `foo`) needs that return type, then I can call `newVar` freely within `foo` and any function I call in `foo`. Can I just return some garbage of that type?

Comment: OK, I see part of your problem - the `do` notation for the `main` function that is the entry point from the outside world is working on the `IO` monad, whereas for the rest of your code it'll be working on the `Supply` monad. I've added an example of this.

Comment: BTW if you also want to use `IO` in the rest of your code you'll either need a "monad transformer" (`SupplyT` on the wiki page) or to use an `IORef` to pass around the name supply instead. That adds another layer to understand, so probably best to get to grips with this style first.

Comment: I think you may have misread, it's a t0 not IO. I'm not doing any IO or using that monad (unless you're saying I need to?) I'll take a close look at your new example code. BTW you've earned a fat bounty if I figure this out.

Comment: I didn't misread `t0` - I guessed that you are using `IO` because of what you said about calling `runSupplyVars` from inside "the first line of my `do`", from which I inferred that it might well be from `main` which is in the `IO` monad. The way the `Supply` monad works is that you build up a big operation of type `Supply [Char] a` and then you get rid of it in "pure" code using `runSupplyVars`. So no matter where you call it from, the call will look more like `let result = runSupplyVars realProgram` than `do p <- runSupplyVars`.

Comment: So many `do` blocks and strange types, it seems as messy as my original code. I'm just going back to accumulator-passing, at least I understood how that worked.

Comment: Fair enough - there is an overhead to using monads, but they really come into their own in more complicated scenarios where they can hide a lot more boilerplate than a single state variable. Using one here also makes it somewhat harder to screw up and accidentally reuse the same variable name.